# R: How to add a column to a dataframe with in each row the cumulative sum of all its previous rows?

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have a simple question but I cannot find the answer on stackoverflow. Maybe I am using the wrong search terms. Anyways this is my question:

I want to add a column to a dataframe with in each row the cumulative sum of all its previous rows. For example I have dataframe X with columns V1 and V2. In this case V3 in the example is the added column I wish to create:

X=

```
V1 V2  V3
1  0.5 0.5
2  2.0 2.5
3  1.9 4.4
4  0.0 4.4
5  5.1 9.5
```

The actual data frame on which I want to apply this is actually a lot bigger (5000 rows). Tips or solutions anyone? Would be great!

Comment: So searching for `cumulative sum` and `r` didn't lead you to `cumsum`?

Comment: Tested it in my google and it seems that this is the first hit. +1 joran :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `cumsum()` function will do the trick, but since you want it across multiple columns you'll need to get the sum across rows first. This can be done with the `apply()` function. Assuming I understand what you're looking for, here is an example:

```
> set.seed(2)
> dat <- data.frame(a=round(rnorm(10),2),b=round(rnorm(10),2),c=round(rnorm(10),2))
> dat$cumsum <- cumsum(apply(dat,1,sum))
> dat
       a     b     c cumsum
1  -0.90  0.42  2.09   1.61
2   0.18  0.98 -1.20   1.57
3   1.59 -0.39  1.59   4.36
4  -1.13 -1.04  1.95   4.14
5  -0.08  1.78  0.00   5.84
6   0.13 -2.31 -2.45   1.21
7   0.71  0.88  0.48   3.28
8  -0.24  0.04 -0.60   2.48
9   1.98  1.01  0.79   6.26
10 -0.14  0.43  0.29   6.84
```

Comment: His sum is only over column `V2`.

Comment: Then I mis-read is question and his question shouldn't have been asked in the first place. There is no doubt many examples of applying cumsum() across a single variable.

Comment: If your interpretation were correct which (it does not appear to be), it would probably be faster to just use `cumsum(rowSums(dat))`.

Comment: true. i frequently forget about those one-off vectorized functions like rowSums()